# Center multiple UILabels on a line

Tags: ios, swift, view, uilabel, center

I want to horizontally center multiple UILabels - as a group - on a line in Interface Builder.  One the straight view controller i could not figure out how to do this.  I read comments about place the UILabels in a View and then centering the view in the view controller.  When I tried this, overtime I said to update frames in the interface builder, the View would be resized down to nothing.  (i.e. its height and width would be set to 0 by IB).  I need to know how to get this to work in interface builder.

An example of a line containing multiple labels I want horizontally centered is below.  The braces simply indicate the start and end of each label and are not art of the text.  The <- 6 -> is meant to indicate the trailing space from label 1 to label 2 is 6

Label 1              Label 2
[Rating: 0.0]<- 6 ->[Distance: 125.34 Kilometers]

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Here is an EXACT example of what I have done and it does not work:

1. Create a new view controller in IB
2. Place a page label at the top of the page centered horizontally and aligned to the top of the layout guide.
3. Add a view with the following constraints on the page:

[image: View Constraints]

4. Now add two labels to the view with the following constraints:
   [image: Label Constraints]
5. Once this is done I get the following error and updating the frames will cause it to be give a height and width of 0
   [image: Error Message]

Here is what the page looks like in IB:
[image]

I need the height and width of the view to size automatically so that I have put a multiline label in the view and have all the contents of the view treated as a group and centered on the page.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you please share the screen shot of your expected output.

Comment: no I can't because I can't get IB to work to display it.  The expected layout would be the two labels positioned per their constraints with the view and the view horizontally centered and its height and width set based on the two labels that it contains.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a snapshot of a working set of all the constraints on an abbreviated layout that produces an always-centered view that automatically resizes with the child views (i.e., as the content of any label changes, the view grows or shrinks around it).

Important to your solution, the view has neither a height nor width constraint; its size is constrained entirely by its descendant constraints.

[image]

The key is that every component has a direct or indirect constraint from which its size and position are specified or can be inferred.  For example, in order for the view to infer its width, the child labels must have a leading space constraint on the first label, a trailing space constraint on the last label, and a horizontal space constraint between interior labels.  Those constraints plus the contents of the labels allow the width of the view to be inferred ... and force the view to dynamically conform to that width.

The same applies for the view's height.  For example, you can specify the top and bottom space of just one label, or all of them.  If just one, the remaining labels can be vertically aligned with it (see "Align Center Y to: Label1" in the screenshot).

Comment: The challenge is -- if I set a width for the view versus having it auto size based on its contents - while the view itself might be centered in the master container, the contents of the view will not be centered as their width with change each time.  (ie. 2.3 Miles versus 240.40 Kilometers.)  So how do I get the view itself to auto size its width base on its contents?

Comment: You're wanting the containing view to change size, or just the labels that contain variable data?

Comment: Both  -- Remember the problem is that I have four labels on a line - which all can be of varying width due to different languages and values - and I want them treated like a group so the group of them are centered on the line.  That means that each label within the view will resize at run based on its contents and the view itself will need to resize and adjust it center within the page at run time based on the contents of the labels it contains.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the additional context.  Instead of giving the containing view a width constraint, then, ensure your leading space and trailing space constraints on the first and last labels are set (to, say, 20), and that the horizontal spacing between the interior labels is set.  Sounds like you don't want width constraints on any of the labels.  The result will be a containing view auto-resizes based on the text in the labels.

Comment: Kevin I believe that is what I tried and every time I updated the frames the view was updated to 0 width and 0 height.  Have you tried it and received different results?

Comment: Yep, see the screenshots I added to the answer that show the constraints and a preview of them on an iPhone and iPad.  It auto-resizes to any changes in the label contents.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77567/discussion-between-kevin-owens-and-george-m-ceaser-jr).

Comment: Kevin - Thanks for the update and I seem to have gotten it to work now based on the guidelines you provided.  Thanks again for all your help