# iOS swift multi-line UILabel in a view

Tags: ios, uiview, autolayout, uilabel, multiline

I would like to accomplish what is seen in the image below in Interface Builder.  Basically two labels - one multi-line and one note - inside a view and the view centered horizontally on the page.  So to be clear, I cannot put a width constraint on the view or the centering will not work correctly. [image: Exmaple]

I can get the label with the actual hours to multi-line when it is not in a view but when I place it in a view and set up the Top, Left and Right constraints - the label reverts back to a single line.

below are the constraints and attributes for the label in the view and a picture of what IB does when i update the frames.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Attributes]
[image: Hours Value Constraints]

There are the constraints for the label with just the work Hours in it:
[image: Hours Label Constraints]

This is what it looks like after I update the frames

[image: After update frames]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either your multi-line label, or the outer view needs to have its width constrained in some way, otherwise the label will expand its width to whatever it needs to accommodate the text on one line. If that line is long enough, the text will run off the edge of the view, which is what appears to be happening in your last image.

**After Edit:**

To make the view centered when the list of hours is short, but still allow the view to be wide when the hours list is long, give the outer view a <= width constraint to the superview. In IB select your view then the superview, and choose "equal widths", and then edit that to be <=. The default hugging priority will keep that outer view small if the list is short, but if the list grows long enough to go to multiple lines, you still have the width constraint to force it to do so.

I found that adding this <= constraint in IB didn't work correctly on rotation. If the label was multi-line in portrait, and thus the labelsView (the view containing the 2 labels) was expanded to the full width of the screen, on rotation labelsView maintained that same width, instead of adjusting to the new size. I think this is a bug in the system. Fortunately, adding the same constraint in code, worked fine.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: labelsView, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .LessThanOrEqual, toItem: self.view, attribute: .Width, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
}
```

Comment: Please look at the desired outcome for the two labels.  The word hours that  is bold is one label and the other label shows the actual hours.  The label with the word Hours: in it has a top, bottom and left constraints.  The second label has top bottom left and right constraints.  The issue is not the view resizing the issue is that the second label with the actual hours in it is not going to multiple lines.  I have updated the question with the constraints for both labels

Comment: Also one more note about the previous answer that is 100% incorrect and I don't want people to believe it is true, the outer view does not needs to have constraints that constrain its width; either a width constraint, or constraints to both sides of its superview.  For a discussion of exactly what is needed to get the view auto sizing to work please see this SO article http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30158471/center-multiple-uilabels-on-a-line

Comment: @GeorgeMCeaserJr With a multi-line label, the outer view (or the label itself) does need a width constraint. If you don't have that (and that's your main problem), then the label expands its width to accommodate the text on one line, and if that line is long enough, it will run off the screen -- that is what I'm seeing in your image. Something constraining the width is need to force the text onto multiple lines, otherwise, how would the label know where to break the line?

Comment: OK - I tried it with width constraint anti does work but this will not accomplish what I need. The object of this is to have the two label treated as a group in the view and have the view be horizontally centered on the page.  Providing a width property for the view will make it so the two labels within the view are not centered horizontally on the page.  I did state this in my question but it may not be clear so I will update my question to attempt to make it clearer.   Any other ideas of how to get this to work?

Comment: @GeorgeMCeaserJr I'm still not sure what you want centered. It sounds like you want the view that contains the 2 labels to be centered. If that view has a centerX constraint and a fixed width, it will be centered. If that's not what you want, please clarify.

Comment: I want the entire contents of the view centered as explained in the question.  Setting a width for the view will not work as the contents of both label can change due to different languages or values.  The hours can be something is short as M-F 12-14 or something very long. I could set the view width very small but then it would look very silly if the hours list was very long.  What I want is for a view like the first one shown in my question - with two different labels in it, to be auto sized to its contents and then centered on the page.  From what I am gathering that is not possible.

Comment: @GeorgeMCeaserJr I think it is possible, and I've edited my answer to show you how. Try that, and see if that meets your needs.

Comment: So I did some testing.  The challenge is that any time you enter a width you are going to have scenario where this is unused space on the sides of the outer view while the internal text is going to multiple lines.  I don't consider this a good UI design and I am choosing not to implement it that way in my solution.  I need the view to truly resize itself to the contents including the multiline line label so all space on the line is used before the multi-line label would wrap to a second line. Any suggestion on how to make this happen?

Comment: @GeorgeMCeaserJr, yeah, I was about to update my answer to make it do that, so I have. The key is to make the view have a <= width constraint relative to its superview's width, rather than a fixed number. this works fine for different screen sizes, but it doesn't seem to work correctly for rotation -- I'm still looking into why that is so. It seems like a bug to me.

Comment: @GeorgeMCeaserJr One more correction. I found that adding the constraint I mentioned in my last comment in code, instead of IB, caused it to work properly (so this is definitely a storyboard bug).

Comment: I have actually clarified this several times.  Please look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30158471/center-multiple-uilabels-on-a-line  This is what I am trying to accomplish now with a multiline UILabel in the view.

Comment: I know what you're trying to accomplish, and I think the code I have now does that. Does it not? When I test it, it expands to fill the horizontal space until it needs to go to multiple lines, and it stays centered.

Comment: OK I will look at the updated answer.  Thank you for all of your help. :)  One request -- Swift code examples please? :)